# accessing complex json data

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

The  `<cfoutput>#cfhttp.FileContent#</cfoutput>` of a web api call is producing the following output:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2013-12-08",
        "open": {
            "Webmail": 6717,
            "Phone": 8086,
            "Other": 1224,
            "Tablet": 2374,
            "Desktop": 1967
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-12-09",
        "open": {
            "Webmail": 15213,
            "Phone": 18445,
            "Other": 2968,
            "Tablet": 3944,
            "Desktop": 5014
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2013-12-10",
        "open": {
            "Webmail": 432,
            "Phone": 403,
            "Other": 39,
            "Tablet": 115,
            "Desktop": 106
        }
    }
]
```

I am wondering, is it possible to access Webmail,Phone,Tablet etc in order to plot a amchart as mentioned in the jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/TQxYB/

Comment: have you looked at coldfusion charting cfchart tag ?

Comment: I don't want to use cfchart tag but amchart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya we can get access to its childs in json.
You just need to run for loop.
I have tried one demo hope u'l get some help.

http://jsfiddle.net/qthpt/

```
var chart;
var legend;

var json = [
        {
            "date": "2013-12-08",
            "open": {
                "Webmail": 6717,
                "Phone": 8086,
                "Other": 1224,
                "Tablet": 2374,
                "Desktop": 1967
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-12-09",
            "open": {
                "Webmail": 15213,
                "Phone": 18445,
                "Other": 2968,
                "Tablet": 3944,
                "Desktop": 5014
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-12-10",
            "open": {
                "Webmail": 432,
                "Phone": 403,
                "Other": 39,
                "Tablet": 115,
                "Desktop": 106
            }
        }
    ];
 var chartData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            chartData.push({
                "date":json[i].date,
                "webmail":json[i].open.Webmail
            });
        }



AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // PIE CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.titleField = "date";
    chart.valueField = "webmail";
    chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
    chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
    chart.outlineThickness = 2;
    chart.balloonText = "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>";

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
```